# Guitar to PCIe line in

Tags: electric-guitar

Can I plug my guitar cable directly to the line-in on my computers PCIe audio card?  If not, why, is it a voltage or impedance mismatch?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with plugging most guitars directly into a computer line in jack is that the guitar output level is very low and a line in jack does not have an amplifier with an appropriate amount of gain to amplify the low signal to a usable level.

What is needed to make the raw output of a guitar pickup usable is a *preamp*. Amps designed for electric guitars include a preamp. Some acoustic and electric guitars have preamps built into them - you can tell if your guitar has a preamp by whether it uses a battery. If your guitar has a battery compartment and you make sure it has a fresh battery in it, then you might be able to plug directly into the line in jack. If your guitar does not have any battery compartment, then you’ll need a preamp of some kind.

Most microphones also require a preamp, so many audio interfaces designed to be used for recording music include mic preamps that can be used as a guitar preamp as well. In those cases, the impedance (which in this situation might be best viewed as the ratio of voltage to current in the source signal) of microphones is much lower than that of guitars, so a separate “high impedance” input that is the right kind of jack as well is included to allow you to plug your guitar into the mic preamp.

While you could try to find a suitable preamp that is not part of an audio interface to use between your guitar and your existing line in jack, i think your research and money would be better spent finding an audio interface designed for recording music.

Comment: Another issue is a loss of high frequencies due to a low pass filter formed by coil inductance, cable capacity and input impedance. Active pickups are less prone to that. Also connecting the guitar via a **non true bypass** guitar effect pedal may help, as they typically have low impedance outputs.

Answer (score -1):

Try.  Nothing will break.  Inputs on today's gear are a lot more forgiving than they used to be.  You might find the Line In has enough gain available to get useable level from a guitar.  (It would have helped if you'd told us WHICH 'PCIe audio card' it is.)

If you can't get a useful sound from direct connection you'll have to investigate preamps.

Comment: The problem is that guitar output with passive pickups less forgiving. They need input to have impedance in range of hundreds of kilo-ohms to some megaohms and line inputs tend to be hundreds of ohms.

Comment: On today's gear you often find multi-purpose voltage-sensing inputs with moderately high impedance and  a wide range of amplification.  Not lot of 300 ohm line inputs around any more!   It's worth a try.