# When I use the Aux In on my guitar amp the sound only goes through when I touch the aux with my finger

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, audio

I want to plug in my guitar and my phone into my amp so I can play over a song, the whole system works properly but can only hear my phone when I touch the aux head, otherwise it’s a loud buzz and ticking, maybe a loop. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Guitar to PCIe line in](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/110656/guitar-to-pcie-line-in)

Comment: The aux in is probably broken and only makes contact correctly when you’re touching it

Comment: It's probably struggling with a mismatched pinout too. Phone has TRRS, amp wants TS. Without knowing amp & phone we'll never know.